# Is it rude to wait to deposit a cheque?

Tags: salary, canada

A few weeks ago, I received a reimbursement cheque for a company perk from my employer. I have not gone down to my bank to deposit it simply because it is inconvenient (but not impossible) for me to do so.

Long story short, I don't drive anymore so I would have to take a different bus there and back, causing me to take between an extra half to full hour out of my day. Because of this, and that I will soon have other banking to do, my plan was to gather up all my necessary work and do it all at once, but this means that I would have had this cheque in my possession for *almost a month*, a period so long that I may receive another one for the same purpose (perk recurs monthly).

My bottom line question: **is it rude for me to do this? Should I be depositing cheques as soon as I get them?**

Comment: Can't you deposit with a mobile app? At least in the US BofA allows that.

Comment: Can you ask them to make it a direct deposit?  Or can you find a bank close to your home or office and open an account and deposit it there and then transfer the money electronically to your main bank or leave it there to accumulate until you need it?

Comment: Wells Fargo allows mobile deposits too.

Comment: Turns out my bank does support cheque deposits via the app. I don't normally receive cheques, so I was not familiar with this feature. Thanks!

Comment: My local credit union has had an app for years that allows deposits. I thought everyone would by now. Maybe you should think about a new bank if your current one isn't convenient.

Comment: I don't see how you can be *rude* by not depositing... you can do whatever you want with your cheque, even burn it if you desire. If any, it is not *optimal* to do so, as in that time you don't deposit you can misplace the cheque and also you are not gaining interests from that money. I agree with the others that a digital way of depositing could help you greatly, as well as a direct deposit from your company to your bank account.

Comment: @GrayCygnus, in this particular case how you handle this check does matter.  Maybe not to the question of rudeness, but this check may have tax implications for OPs employer and should be handled more appropriately.  Especially to the point of destroying or never depositing.  In that case employer will have claimed to have provided certain funds to OP and the money will never have moved.

Comment: Can you just post it to the bank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it rude for me to do this?

It isn't really a matter of rudeness or not. You should do what in convenient for you - so long as it isn't causing problems for the company.

What do I mean by "causing problems for the company"?

Mainly cash-flow and planning - they might be expecting you to draw the cheque immediately and be planning accordingly (doubtful, but can be true for very small businesses). If you draw a bunch of these at once, this can cause them real issues, for example (you might think of it as bad planning on their side and not really your problem).

There are also a few practical issues for you to consider here - bounced cheques and expired cheques are the big ones. In regards to the former - you would want to know as soon as possible - that, by itself is good enough a reason to cash a cheque as soon as possible. Where I am from, a cheque will expire 6 months after it was issues - if you keep cheques around for long, you might end up without the money at all.

> Should I be depositing cheques as soon as I get them?

Ideally, yes. There is no gain for anyone to not do so and only upsides.

Comment: If a company writes you a check, shouldn't they act as if that money has already been deducted from their accounts? I'm curious how this could cause them any kinds of cash flow problems if they are keeping their books properly.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - you're assuming every company keeps their books properly... This may not always be the case - particularly for small operations.

Comment: @brhans in any case, if that company does not keep their books properly it is their problem. If your cheque is rejected because of lack of funds it will also be an inconvenient to you (no money on the bank) but it means more trouble to your company, as they *still* have to pay you that money and sometimes rejected cheques also mean a rejection fine has to be paid.

Answer (score 5):

Cheques are valid for 6 months in Canda I believe, and the sort of timeframe you are talking about (<1 month) isn't outrageous, I highly doubt they will even notice.

On the off chance they mention it I'd just reply commenting that you haven't gotten around to it yet because of the logistics of getting to your bank.

Comment: They would notice as cash reconciliation is done at least monthly.

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**

Unless the owner is personally writing and signing the checks, no one will even notice until the check expires without clearing.

On a side note, it's very likely your bank's app allows online check deposit.

Comment: Downvote?  Really?  No explanation?  Totally unhelpful and wrong.